# How to set value to a Map in a method for testcase?

Tags: java, junit

I have this map metadata and in the last line where i am sending this map as a parameter to saveReport method, I want to write a testcase where i want to send metadata as null. How can i set value for metadata (Map) as null. How can i pass value of metadata as null in testcase.

```
 public List<Response> fetchReport (final Request request)
    {
       
        final Map<String, String> metadata = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        ReportUtils.createMetadata(metadata, Constant.STATUS,
            List.of(request.getStatus()));
        ReportUtils.createMetadata(metadata, Constant.SCOPE,
            List.of(request.getScope()));
        responses.addAll(
            request.Instances().stream()
                .flatMap(instanceObj ->
                    findCriteria(instanceObj,
                        request.getScope(), request
                            .getStatus()).stream()
                        .map(this::transformDBObj)
                )
                .toList()
        );
        saveReport(responses, test, metadata);
        return responses;
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused.  If you want to pass null, just do it?  Perhaps you need a parameter that gives the test this control.  If you have a test case example that may help to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your public method (that anyone could call) is fetchReport, whereas saveReport is private. Nobody can call saveReport with a null map, the map initialization being the very first thing you do when fetchReport is called. What is the point of testing saveReport with a null metadata? Who can ever end up calling it like that?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass a `null` value for the `metadata` parameter in your `saveReport` method during testing, you can simply pass `null` as an argument when calling the `fetchReport` method. Here's how you can do it:

```java
@Test
public void testFetchReportWithNullMetadata() {
    // Assuming you have set up your test environment and objects
    
    // Call fetchReport method with a request object
    List<Response> result = yourTestClassObject.fetchReport(yourRequestObject);
    
    // Add assertions or verifications as needed
    
    // Check if saveReport was called with metadata as null
    verify(yourMockObject).saveReport(any(), any(), isNull());
}
```

In this test case, you are calling the `fetchReport` method with a request object, and since you're interested in testing when `metadata` is null, you don't explicitly pass any `metadata` object. Then, you verify that the `saveReport` method was called with `metadata` parameter as `null` using a mocking framework like Mockito.

Comment: saveReport is a private method , M getting error here.   verify(yourMockObject).saveReport(any(), any(), isNull());